# Viewstate doesn't work for a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, viewstate

I am in the following situation. One aspx page with one ascx inside which contains a checkbox. 
At the aspx page I have EnableViewState=true and `ViewStateMode=disabled`. Then for every control which needs view state I overrided `ViewStateMode=Enabled`. 
The ascx also has ViewStateMode enabled also on the declarion in the aspx page but also in the header of the ascx page. Also the check box has it set. 
Howevere when clicked it doesn't fire the `selected_changed` event. It posts back because it has `Auto-postback=true` but doesn't fire the event.

If in the master aspx page I set `ViewStateMode` enabled it works. But I can't understand why it doesn't override it...

Comment: Can you try enabling trace and see the viewstate? Like this: [How to: View ASP.NET Trace Information with the Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx)

Comment: I've tried to reproduce by setting only these: 

 - site.master (viewstatemode=false)
 - default.aspx (viewstatemode=false)
 - usercontrol1 (viewstatemode=false)

The event CheckBox1_CheckedChanged is fired.
And I don't need to enable ViewStateMode onto the checkbox.

I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking time. I enabled trace, in form collection I have 2 references to the checkbox: one in event target, and one chkreturn with value on. I dont' know what these mean or if I'm supposed to be looking at something else. What is curious is that right next to the checkbox is a dropdown list and for that the selected index is fired...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I take a look at the [Control.ViewStateMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx) on the MSDN documentation.

Pay attention at:

> **The ViewStateMode property of a page or a control has an effect only if the EnableViewState property is set to true**. If the EnableViewState property is set to false, view state will be turned off even if the ViewStateMode property is set to Enabled.

So correct way to handle ViewState is to:

- leave EnableViewState="true" (is the default) everywhere
- ViewStateMode="false" master page. This way each derived page and control inherit ViewStateMode and does not output viewstate in html
- enable viewstate only on the checkbox by setting ViewStateMode="true"

Comment: Hi. Well, I'm doing right like it says: I have EnableViewState=true and ViewStateMode=disabled for the page and then overwrite only viewstatemode where necesseraly. Anyway, I think this is a code problem. I created a dummy checkbox with an empty event and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are toggling your viewstate on/off ASAP -> Init or InitComplete.